# Go with X11 or Wayland for a fresh install

Tags: x11, wayland

I understand Wayland is the protocol meant to replace X11, but I don't see a real breakthrough yet. From an end-user perspective, if I want to install a fresh distribution, should I go with Wayland or wait a bit and install X11? Or yet another display technology?

Comment: You go with what's the default of your distro and don't worry about it.

Comment: Since all X11 apps are not yet wayland compatible, you'll still need the Xorg-server to be installed. anyway. So your question is not (at the time of this comment) wayland exclusive-or Xorg. It is Xorg with or without the wayland patches ? The other decisive question being answered by the compositor you'll be using and your graphic card driver.

Comment: @MC68020 what do you mean by “Xorg with or without the Wayland patches”? There’s `Xwayland`, and there are standalone X servers, but they serve different purposes and the distinction doesn’t help answer the question IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specific requirements. e.g. better touch screen support or using most screen recording apps, that would incline you to choose one over the other, like Marcus said, then use what comes by default.